# Why not delta of Call option is stochastic or random variable?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks, delta

**Delta of an option is defined as ratio of change in price of call option to change in price of underlying securities**. If, $c_t$ is call option price at time $t$ and $S_t$ is the price of underlying securities, then the delta of call option is:

$$\Delta(t)=\frac{\partial c_t}{\partial S_t}$$

If **change in $dS_t$ ie $(S_{t+dt} -S_t)$ is random**, which by definition is true, then **delta ($\Delta (t)$, computed at time t) must be random variable (instead of known constant)** as it involve $dS_t$ in denominator.  But under the **Black-Scholes model**, the delta of European of Call option (which is written as $N(d_1)$ or $\Phi (d_2)$) is deterministic variable (ie known with certainty) at time $t$.

**I want to know why delta of a call option is deterministic quantity, why not it is random variable?** If possible, please provide both logical reasoning and formal derivation.

Comment: My 2cents: It is defined as a partial derivative. It cannot be anything but deterministic as such. Remember that the call price knowing the filtration $\mathcal {F}_t $ *is* a deterministic function of $S_t $.

Comment: In other words: $\Delta(t) $ is random conditionally on $\mathcal {F}_0$, true... but not conditionally on $\mathcal {F}_t$ (since it is $\mathcal {F}_t$-measurable, because $S_t $ is adapted to $\mathcal {F}_t$).

Comment: @Quantuple: If at time $t$, $\Delta(t)$ is known and, of course, not random. However, we look the process $\{\Delta(t) \mid t \ge 0\}$ today, then it is a stochastic process. For future time $t$, we say that if we are there, but we are actually not, and we can have many paths $\omega$ to get there. This is how stochastic process coming into place.

Comment: @Gordon: Pardon me, but I don't understand how this differs from/is in conflict with what I said.

Comment: @Quantuple: I was not saying that your statement is wrong. I meant to emphasis that $\Delta(t)$ is stochastic.

Comment: @Gordon: totally agree, then.

Comment: @Quantuple I think my question is misunderstood. I am not saying $\Delta(t)$ as a process is deterministic, but I want to emphasize that $\Delta(t)$ computed at time $t$ must be random quantity, because it involves $dS_t$ in denominator, which by virtue is random, hence $\Delta(t)$ must be random.

Comment: Is it the Leibniz notation $\partial C $ over $\partial S $, which makes you say "because $dS$ at the denominator is stochastic"? This is merely a notation, don't forget a partial derivative (as any derivative) is defined in the limit of that precise $\partial S $ tending towards 0. $\Delta_t $ is deterministic (knowing $\mathcal {F}_t$), but I guess you could say $\Delta _ t dS_t $ is a random quantity (second term of Ito's lemma applied to the option price).

Comment: perhaps what the OP is really asking is that why do we ignore the d on the delta when deriving the BS formula? this has been discussed in many places eg peter carr has a note on it, i devote a section of my book the concepts and practice of mathematical finance to it.  Essentially it's because there's an implicit bond holding done in such a way that $d(\Delta S_t + \alpha_t B_t) = \Delta dS_t + \alpha_t dB_t.$ i.e. self financing condition

Comment: I would also stress that,, by definition, in a partial derivative, only the variable of interest (the one with respect to which you compute the derivative) is allowed to move, **all the other variables are constant**. Hence the $dS $ you talk about is a pure 'in place' move... as if time did not pass. Similarly when you derive with respect to $t $ you do it for fixed $\omega $, see https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143186/derivative-of-a-random-variable-w-r-t-a-deterministic-variable&ved=0ahUKEwiB-LGQ7snLAhXI_w4KHZjMDrUQFggZMAA&usg=AFQj

Comment: As @Quantuple pointed out, the denominator in delta is $\partial S_t$, which is not the same as $dS_t$. For $\partial S_t$, the time $t$ is held fixed, that is, from $S_t$ to $S_t+h$, while $dS_t$ is for the change $S_{t+\delta t}-S_t$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, at time $t$,
\begin{align*}
d_1(t) = \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K} + (r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}) (T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}},
\end{align*}
which is a function of $S_t$, and then, it is a random quantity. Consequently, the delta $N(d_1(t))$ is also a random quantity.

Note that, at time $t$, $N(d_1(t))$ is known. However, $\{N(d_1(t)) \mid t \ge 0\}$ is a stochastic process adapted to the filtration of the equity process $\{S_t \mid t \ge 0\}$, that is, $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: $S_t$ is known at time $t$.

Comment: Do you want to say that Delta also follow a distribution? If yes, can you please specify?

Comment: at time $t$, $S_t$ is known. However, we are looking at it from today. For a Brownian motion $W_t$, it is also known at time $t$, but we do not say it is deterministic, as we consider it from today.

Comment: As the delta is random, then it has a distribution, which can be derived from the distribution of $S_t$..

Comment: writing $W_t$ as random variable is general expression. Think logically, how  can  at time $t$ the stock price $S_t$ be random variable?

Comment: The same logic as why $W_t$ is random even it is known at time $t$.

Comment: Distribution of stock price $S_T$ is conditional. It is always written as: $S_T|S_t \sim \Phi ( *. *)$

Comment: Conditional distribution itself is random.

Comment: $W_t$ can not  be a random if it is known at time $t$.

Comment: But in conditional distribution, $S_t$ is not random if it is known at time $t$.

Comment: For any process $\{X_t \mid t \geq 0\}$, $X_t$ is known at time $t$.

Comment: I think my question is misunderstood. I am not saying $\Delta(t)$ as a process is deterministic, but I want to emphasize that $\Delta(t)$ computed at time $t$ must be random quantity, because it involves $dS_t$ in denominator, which by virtue is random, hence $\Delta(t)$ must be random.

Answer (score 3):

Since we are dealing with the change in the value of the call option in relation to the change in the value of the stock price, we are looking at the simple slope of the function. We do not need to know how much the stock price will change in order to estimate the slope.

In the absence of gamma, the stock price could change 2% or 1% and this wouldn't change the delta. Let's say we have a simple equation, y = mx + b. m is the impact that a change in x has on the change in y, which is the same idea behind delta. If we know how y responds to changes in x, we can deterministically define m and it is not a random variable.

Comment: My initial question is why delta is deterministic quantity at time $t$, when $dS_t$ is stochastic? In your equation $y = mx + b$, if change in $x$ is random, then how $m$ can be known with certainty?

Comment: My short answer is because a derivative doesn't depend on how much the independent variable changes. I assume based on your question that you are not opposed to the Black Scholes equation. The derivative of the Black Scholes equation with respect to the stock price is delta. And, this is denoted by the partial derivative. A derivative does not rely on the amount of the change of the denominator because it is assumed to approach zero, and the derivative is simply the instantaneous slope immediately around the given point, or call value.

Comment: @Neeraj: your question is equivalent to questioning Ito's lemma: $dC_t = \partial_t C dt + \partial_S C dS_t + 1/2 \partial_{SS} C d\langle S, S \rangle_t$